# Ember 1.12.0 instance initializer: deferReadiness method doesn't exist

Tags: ember.js

In ember's blog post about 1.12 release, mentions an example using `application.deferReadiness` inside an instance initializer. However, it doesn't seem to be working. The first parameter to the `initialize` function doesn't have a `deferReadiness` method. Any ideas?

Comment: how many arguments are passed to the initialize function? Just a single instead of 2 as ember 1.11 had?

Comment: Yeah just a single as the example: `export function initialize(application) {
  application.deferReadiness();
}`

Comment: Instance initializers are still new to me, but from what I have read, you won't be able to `deferReadiness()` at the instance initializer because at that point the application is already `ready`. There's also one parameter passed to `initialize` and it's `instance`. See [here](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_deprecate-access-to-instances-in-initializers)

Comment: According to the [blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/13/ember-1-12-released.html) example it should have worked...

Comment: Looks like a bug. I'd let the deprecations slide for now. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's reasonable to post  [@tomdale explanation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10256#issuecomment-113846021) here as an answer.

**@tomdale**: "It's not possible to defer app readiness in an instance initializer, since by definition instance initializers are only run after the app has finished booting.

Sidebar on the semantics of application booting: "App readiness" (as in, `deferReadiness(`) and `advanceReadiness()`) refers to whether all of the code for the application has loaded. Once all of the code has loaded, a new instance is created, which is your application.

To restate, the lifecycle of an Ember application running in the browser is:

1. Ember loads.
2. You create an Ember.Application instance global (e.g.
   App).
3. At this point, none of your classes have been loaded yet.
4. As your JavaScript file is evaluated, you register classes on the
   application (e.g. `App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend(…);`)
5. Ember waits for DOM ready to ensure that all of your JavaScript
   included via `<script>` tags has loaded.
6. **Initializers are run**.
7. If you need to lazily load code or wait for additional setup, you can call **`deferReadiness()`**.
8. Once everything is loaded, you can call **`advanceReadiness()`**.
9. At this point, we say that the `Application` is
   ready; in other words, we have told Ember that all of the classes
   (components, routes, controllers, etc.) that make up the app are
   loaded.
10. A new instance of the application is created, and **instance
    initializers are run**.
11. Routing starts and the UI is rendered to the
    screen.

If you want to delay showing the UI because there is some runtime setup you need to do (for example, you want to open a WebSocket before the app starts running), the **correct solution** is to use the `beforeModel/model/afterModel` hooks in the `ApplicationRoute`. All of these hooks allow you to return a promise that will prevent child routes from being evaluated until they resolve.

Using `deferReadiness()` in an initializer is an **unfortunate hack** that many people have come to rely on. I call it a hack because, unlike the model promise chain in the router, it breaks things like error and loading substates. By blocking rendering in initializers, IMO you are creating a worse experience for users because they will not see a loading or error substate if the promise is slow or rejects, and most of the code I've seen doesn't have any error handling code at all. This leads to apps that can break with just a blank white screen and no indication to the user that something bad has happened."

See also discussion: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11247